# Get Windows DefaultApp path

Tags: java, windows, email

I'm codding a program that send a mail with the default mail app of windows including an attachment.

In 1 hand I can open default app with :

`Desktop.getDesktop().mail(URI)`

In the other hand I can open Outlook with an attachment with :

`new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\OUTLOOK.EXE","/a","D:\\Users\\berna\\Documents\\myDocument.txt").start();`

As I can't attatch file with "mailto:", is there a way to get path of the default app ".exe" used by windows to send mail ? I mean, windows does stock this value somewhere...

Comment: Even if you had the path of that .exe, there would be no guarantee that `/a` would attach a file for programs other than Outlook.

Comment: Yea i saw that... i found a way to get any Outlook.exe at least but that's limited :/